# Azure blob storage using a WriteStream to upload data

Tags: node.js, azure-blob-storage, node-streams

I need to use a write stream to upload data to a azure blob-storage container in nodejs using `@azure/storage-blob`.

It looks like the `uploadStream` only accepts nodejs ReadStreams.

How would I convert a WriteStream to a ReadStream so that I can pass it into the `uploadStream` function.

Comment: Check if [stream.PassThrough](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_passthrough) could help you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using PassThrough worked!

```js
const stream = new PassThrough()
this.containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(filePath).uploadStream(stream)
return stream
```